# Laravel Resource Route destroy (DELETE) without id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, restful-url

Is it possible to modify Laravel's resource routing so I can direct to the destroy method without an ID? The reason being when I call destroy on my UsersController, I only want to delete the currently authenticated user, not the passed ID.

If I simply remove the `$id` parameter from the destroy method, I get the following error:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 207

I guess I could leave the `$id` there, but I would really rather not require the user to pass the id in the URI.

Thanks

Comment: Since it is 'special' (I mean, not like _other_ resources), I would just make a dedicated route for it

Comment: @watcher it would be nice to keep it all consistent, but thought this might be required. Argh, oh well, thanks for your input.

Comment: Remember that your Routes file basically acts as a piece of documentation for your project.  Having a separate route for a specialized action isn't necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: @watcher Being new to Laravel, I'm always concerned of what each line of code does 'under the hood' and it's efficiency. Obviously something I need to get over! :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can, but you have to add an additional route for that:

```
Route::delete('user', 'UserController@destroyAuthenticated');
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

And then in your controller something like that:

```
public function destroyAuthenticated(){
    Auth::user()->delete();
}
```